# How to check if a String matches elements of an Array with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to make a query to my Movie database that contains a group of genres as a string. The format is on the form `genres = "Drama,Action,War`. What I want to do is a make a query towards this String that checks if the genres string contains one of the elements in my array.

If I have a movie with the genre field `"Drama, Action"` and one with `"Drama, Comedy"` and i make a search with the array `["Action","Comedy"]` I want both of the movies to be returned. If this isn't possible, would it be possible if the genre field was an Array as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose allows you to use regex in a query, so you could try something like this:

```
const getMovies = async (genreArray) => {
    const arrayToRegex = genreArray.join('|')
    const results = await Movies.find(
        { "genres": { "$regex": arrayToRegex, "$options": "i" } } 
    );
}
```